# Hide/Show images does not show up eith even space in between

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 7 icons all with the same size. The icons are displayed next to each other using `display: inline-block;` For the sake of explaining the problem I like to name the icons (A, B, C, D, E, F, and G.)

5 of these icons are viable "ie. (A, B, D, F, G)" and 2 are hidden "(ie. C, E)"

When a user clicks on icon B, I want to hide icon B and show icon C instead. Also, when a user click on icon D I want to hide icon D and show E.

I am able to use `show()` and `hide()` to accomplish what I need. however, the problem is in that the gap between the icons as it is not the same size.

In other words, when icon C becomes viable after clicking on icon B the gap/margin between icon A and icon C will show larger than the gap that was between icon A and icon B.

To demonstrate the problem virtually, I created a [fiddle page](https://jsfiddle.net/grtLd0qk/6/) for review

How can I do the show/hide without changing the gaps "margin" between the 2 images?

Below is my html markup "it is also in the fiddle.

```
<div style="text-align: center; display: block;">

    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <div id="icwsButtonPhoneOff"><img class="interaction" id="disconnect" src="http://s13.postimg.org/4i0cnu18z/icws_red.png" alt="Disconnect Call" title="Disconnect Call"></div>
    </div>

    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <div id="icwsButtonHoldOn"><img class="interaction" id="resume" src="http://s15.postimg.org/fbpwulmcn/icws_hold.png" alt="Resume Call" title="Resume"></div>
    </div>

    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <div id="icwsButtonHoldOff" style="display: none;"><img class="interaction" id="hold" src="http://s17.postimg.org/jsbh1libf/icws_resume.png" alt="Place On Hold" title="Place On Hold"></div>
    </div>

    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <div id="icwsButtonMuteOn"><img class="interaction" id="unmute" src="http://s7.postimg.org/mgr5tqqpz/icws_unmute.png" alt="Un-Mute Call" title="Un-Mute Call"></div>
    </div>

    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <div id="icwsButtonMuteOff" style="display: none;"><img class="interaction" id="mute" src="http://s8.postimg.org/vd71colmp/icws_mute.png" alt="Mute Call" title="Mute Call"></div>
    </div>

    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <div id="icwsButtonTransferCall"><img class="interaction" id="mute" src="http://s18.postimg.org/n4jxcru3p/icws_transfer.png" alt="Transfer Call" title="Transfer Call"></div>
    </div>

    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <div id="icwsButtonConferenceCall"><img class="interaction" id="mute" src="http://s8.postimg.org/i42b42bnl/icws_conference.png" alt="Start a Conference With all Parties" title="Start a Conference With all Parties"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you not separating your styles from your html?

Comment: @scavaJripter is that part of the problem or just for cleaner code? I updated the fiddle by separating the HTML from the CSS.

Comment: Its for cleaner code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing the `display:none;` on the wrong elements. Do the `display:none;` on the parent elements of the image you want to hide.
For example, instead of :

```
<div style="display: inline-block;">
  <div id="icwsButtonMuteOff" style="display: none;"><img class="interaction" id="mute" src="http://s8.postimg.org/vd71colmp/icws_mute.png" alt="Mute Call" title="Mute Call"></div>
</div>
```

do:

```
<div style="display:none;">
  <div id="icwsButtonMuteOff"><img class="interaction" id="mute" src="http://s8.postimg.org/vd71colmp/icws_mute.png" alt="Mute Call" title="Mute Call"></div>
</div>
```

The reason is that all of the blanks spaces and/or line breaks are adding up.

EDIT:

I didn't want to spend much time at all on this fiddle, but look at what i did for the pause icons. Lot less code. 
https://jsfiddle.net/grtLd0qk/10/

Comment: in the style you have 2 display type. which is causing the icons not to show up at all.

Comment: Thank @MikeA .  It was rushed.

Comment: Thank you so much That did it.  anyway you can explain what does classToggle exactly do? it sound like it a class exists it deletes is and it is does not exits it adds it. is this a fair summary? This like will have both buttons working http://jsfiddle.net/grtLd0qk/14/

Comment: I'm not a jquery guy, but yes, `toggleClass()` will check if the element has the class and remove the class if it does, or `toggleClass` will add the class if the element doesn't have it.  It is the same concept as the vanilla javascript `classList.toggle()`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're show/hide the inner div ( the one with id ) but not the outer one. Just do

```js
$('#icwsButtonHoldOff').click(function() {
  $('#icwsButtonHoldOn').parent().show();
  $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

and move `style="display:none;"` to the outer div will do.

Or even better, you can have only one div and assign a common css class to all 7 icons that set `display:inline-block`. This way your javascript will just need to toggle the status, no more `.parent()`